# How to disable scrollbars in node editor?

Tags: interface

In 2.82 scrollbars in node editor is not only useless, but annoying, it's also pop-up, which is very bad. How do I disable them enterely?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can disable scrollbars.
But you can make them transparent.

1. Go to *Preferences > Themes > User Interface > Scroll Bars*
2. Set *Item* alpha value to 0
3. And *Outline* to some less intrusive color (it can't be made transparent)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve the problem. It still pops up and hinders window size changing. It works fine in 2.79. It doesn't even make any sense... why pop-up? That area of a screen still can't be used for anything.